# Can't examine variables in scala code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

When I debug a Scala application in eclipse I get a dialog with this message on start up: Unable to set breakpoints in Main due to missing line number artifacts.

When I try to examine variables I get this error in the expressions window: " [in Main [in [Working copy] Main.scala [in  [in src [in Scala1]]]]] does not exist"

I've tried setting various debug level settings for the Scala compiler including "line" and the highest setting but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I was able to see the contents once after messing with settings but was unable to do again so am wondering if there is a bug to do with bad cached state somewhere.

I am using the Indigo service release of Eclipse with version 2.0.0v2_09 of the Scala plugin.

Comment: Maybe you could try [Scala IDE 2.1 Milestone 1](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala_ide_21_milestone_1). It is said to have improved debugging support.

Comment: I had the same problem and I swap my connection type for "Scala Debuger(socket attached)" and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should **upgrade** to the new version of the Scala IDE !

(Strictly) Prior to 3.0.0, the debugger was the *Java* debugger, with no particular Scala support. But ScalaIDE 3.0.0 shipped with a Scala Debugger that should alleviate the problems you mention, specifically well-positioned breakpoints. You can read [the release notes of 3.0.0 describing the debugger](http://scala-ide.org/blog/3.0-final-announcement.html).

You should even try [the release candidate version of 3.0.1,](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html) it contains fixes for the debugger, specifically skipping breakpoints. Try it, and if any issues remain, you can engage the IDE team [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-ide-user), or [file an issue](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets), or ask another SO question!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Scala IDE for eclipse with the Scala Worksheet pre-installed from the following URL:

[enter link description here](http://typesafe.com/stack/scala_ide_download)
//The URL is from the scala course at coursera

With the Scala Worksheet you can create worksheets and watch the vars at the same time you code